# Not able to run onEndReached in React Native Flatlist component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { newsFetch } from "../actions";
import NewsCard from "../components/NewsCard";

import Spinner from "../components/Spinner";

var self;
class NewsScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pageNo: 1,
            refreshing: false,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.newsFetch();
        self = this;
    }
    renderNewsCard({item}) {
        // console.log(self.props.navigation);
        return(
            <NewsCard item={item} navigationProp={self.props.navigation} />
        );
    }

    loadMoreNews() {
        console.log("Loading more...");
    }

    renderNewsList() {
        if(this.props.loading) { 
            return(
                <Spinner />
            );
        }
        return(
            <FlatList
                    data={this.props.news.news}
                    renderItem={this.renderNewsCard} 
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}

                    // No matter whatever I do, I am not able to run this :
                    onEndReached= {this.loadMoreNews}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
            />
        );
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.renderNewsList()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        news: state.news,
        loading: state.news.loading,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { newsFetch })(NewsScreen);
```

No matter whatever I try, I am not able to run my function `loadMoreNews` when the `flatlist` reaches the end.

Its driving me crazy! I have tried all the stackoverflow questions and answers and I am unable to understand why am I unable to run the function.

I want to be able to reach the end so that I can add an infinite scroll based functionality.

Comment: It doesn't look like `loadMoreNews` does anything except `console.log("Loading more...")` ?

Comment: Can you share all FlatList props which you used?

Comment: @Sankalp did you try to increase onEndReachedThreshold to 0.4 or something like this.I am using like this and that is working fine
 onEndReached={_.debounce(this.endScroll, 500)}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}

Comment: @sdkcyI have given the entire code above..

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar: Yup.. Tried that too.. Doesnt work... No idea!!

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar : I tried it again and it worked!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! If you give your answer, I will mark it as accepted!! :D

Comment: @SankalpSingha now you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

`loadMoreNews` should be arrow function or use bind method. Please update the `loadMoreNews` as following:

```
...
  loadMoreNews = () => {
    console.log("Loading more...");
  }
...
```

Comment: I tried this.. It did not work. I am really confused now lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set onEndReachedThreshold and use like this.

```
 onEndReached={_.debounce(this.endScroll, 500)} 
 onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
```